# My anatomy: What exercizes should I do? Is there any YouTuber/Instgramer that looks like me to help me understand what kind of work-out I should do?

Tags: workout-routines, muscle, strength, workout, anatomy

Musculation should be highly customized, according to the anatomy *e.g.*. I've practiced for almost 2 years, without any result (in term of hypertrophy, strength / weights, etc.)

Below is my current shape. According to my muscular insertions, my muscles (length, shape, etc.), my bone structure (clavicles, etc.): could you recommend me some exercizes, or even a training protocol (I want to work strength / nervous system AND hypertrophy)?

Also, could you give me an example of bodybuilders, Youtubers or Instagramers of my age (15  - 25 yo) that had almost the same shape than me at their early stages? They'd be examples for me to follow.

Comment: “Musculation should be highly customized, according to the anatomy.” Sure, that’s how folks like Eugen Sandow learned to build muscle. However, and this is very important, human anatomy rarely differs so significantly from individual to individual that training plans should be tailored to the individual. Building muscle should be tailored to the anatomy - human anatomy. Individual anatomy is trivial in most cases.

Comment: @JustSnilloc Wrong. For more than a decade, we have known that there are large morphoanatomical differences between individuals, and these explain the differences in the probability of injury between these individuals, the differences in muscle load on a given exercise, and the differences in terms of hypertrophy.

Comment: @JustSnilloc Example: People with a thin rib cage and long arms have an increased risk of overstretched pectoral muscles and therefore 1) injury and 2) increased stress on the anterior deltoids. Another example: people with short clavicles cannot have a wide back (V-shaped), unlike people with long clavicles and will therefore have to work on their lateral deltoids. Another example: people with short biceps have an increased risk of injury during the eccentric phase of the bicep curl. All this can be read in The Delavier Gundill Method, among other (many) sources.

Comment: @JustSnilloc so don't forget to upvote my question please? because I don't know why, but it has been downvoted...

Comment: As the answer states, if you have gone 2 years with no change, you're doing something wrong. Strength and hypertrophy are not necessarily the same goals, nervous system will automatically adapt to your training. And no, unless you really have some weird morphology, a beginner training program does not need to be that individually specific.(And you have links for your claims in the comments? If you could add those into your post, it would help).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user has edited out his pictures, which makes the question incomplete.

Comment: Yes you can close this question ty :)

Answer (score 5):

To be blunt, if you've practiced for 2 years without result, you're probably not doing things correctly. There are plenty of good programs out there, but that's only half the battle. Are you eating correctly? do you get enough sleep consistently? What is your current program? How often do you train?

I would say that you are at a stage where you shouldn't really even consider that X body type has X disadvantage because these things don't really affect the beginner as much. These are things you learn to adapt to with experience, not to use as an excuse.